# Why table creation takes a lot of time in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

"create table" statement takes a lot of time in redshift. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be problem with SQLWORKBENCH that I use to interface with redshift.